# What is the 'meaning' behind $r·n = a·n$

Tags: vectors

I was confused about what the dot product represents and I think I have grasped that now from this post [What does the dot product of two vectors represent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805954/what-does-the-dot-product-of-two-vectors-represent) .

However, I still cannot understand what $r·n = a·n$ represents in the same way. I am not sure if this is the universal notation for it, but I was told that '$r$' is any point on a plane $(x,y,z)$ and '$n$' is the normal to the plane with '$a$' being any known point on the plane. I can't understand why the dot product of the normal and ($O$ - any point on the plane) would be the same as the dot product of the normal and ($O$ - one particular point on the plane) as ($O$ - a point on the plane) would be a different vector every time where n stays constant surely resulting in a different dot product.

Probably haven't articulated my misunderstanding too well but any help appreciated.

Comment: The equation $\vec r \cdot \vec n = \vec a \cdot \vec n$ defines the plane containing the point with position vector $\vec a$ and having normal $\vec a$, when $\vec r$ is taken (as per usual notation) to stand for the position vector of an arbitrary point $(x, y, z)$. For any point $(x, y, z)$ in the plane, so that $r$ is its position vector, then $\vec r - \vec a$ is a vector _lying in the plane_, and therefore perpendicular to $\vec n$ (a normal to the plane). Thus, $\vec n \cdot (\vec r - \vec a) = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to visualize the equation is that if you construct an alternative orthonormal basis in $\mathbb R^3,$
with basis vectors $\mathbf e_1,$ $\mathbf e_2,$ and $\mathbf e_3,$
you can get the coordinates of any vector $\mathbf r$ over the alternative basis by taking the dot product of $\mathbf r$ with each basis vector. 
For example, the first coordinate is
$\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf e_1.$

Given a unit vector $\mathbf n$ normal to some plane, you can make it part of an orthonormal basis by setting $\mathbf e_1=\mathbf n.$
The other two basis vectors then are parallel to the plane. 
If you take an arbitrary vector $\mathbf a$ and then take all vectors $\mathbf r$ such that $\mathbf r \cdot \mathbf n= \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf n,$
those vectors describe a plane through $\mathbf a$ parallel to your initial plane in the same way that all vectors with first coordinate $k$ describe a plane parallel to the plane $x=1.$
If $\mathbf a$ is the position vector of a point in your initial plane then the “parallel” plane is simply the plane you started with.

To *prove* that this all works, you would probably need to do some algebraic manipulations. But once you have proved that it works, you can visualize $\mathbf r\cdot \mathbf n$ as one of the coordinates of $\mathbf r$ in an orthonormal basis with $\mathbf n$ as one of the basis vectors without thinking again about the algebra you used in the proof.

Comment: Not too sure how - considering I've had to google 90% of what you wrote - but that does actually make a good amount of sense. Think I was considering the equation in completely the wrong way so thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 3):

If you rearrange it, it is $$(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{a})\cdot\mathbf{n} = 0.$$
Since $\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{a}$ is the vector joining $\mathbf{a}$ to $\mathbf{r}$, this equation says that $\mathbf{n}$ is orthogonal (perpendicular) to the vector joining $\mathbf{a}$ to $\mathbf{r}$ for any $\mathbf{r}$ on the plane. If you draw a diagram, you should be able to intuitively see that this is the case.

Comment: Yes we were taught that to begin with and I understand that. My issue was I couldn't understand what the final form represented or is it a case of the first form is very easily explainable and then you just have to accept that the rearranged form is true as a result of it following from the original form?